# Adding list to a new list

Tags: c#

Take if from the top. have a list that I return MyTableList.

```
var MyTableList = List<ExportDto>(List);
```

this tableList returns ID's that is needed to select another level from the same table.

```
IEnumerable<int?> rowselect = MyTableList.Where(n => n.ID != null)
                                         .Select(n => n.ID);
```

this provides me with a list of ID's are then returned;
I use a

```
foreach (var item in rowselect)
    getnewlist = getnewinfo.GetSinglerows(item.Value);
```

The main problem is for me Adding this new list and merging it with MyTableList.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you could simplify some of your code like this... `var newList = MyTableList.Where(n => n.ID != null).Select(n => getnewinfo.GetSinglerows(n.ID)).ToList();`

Comment: What issue are you having with adding the new list, avoiding duplicates?

Comment: `var MyTableList = List<ExportDto>(List);` Does that compile?

Comment: I would suggest changing `IEnumerable<int?> rowselect = MyTableList.Where(n => n.ID != null)
                                         .Select(n => n.ID);` to `IEnumerable<int> rowselect = MyTableList.Where(n => n.ID != null)
                                         .Select(n => n.ID.Value);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`List<T>.AddRange Method`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc(v=vs.110).aspx) as following:

```
MyTableList.AddRange(getnewlist );
```